# How to setup Jenkins in scenario when couldn't access master

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have Mac based master behind the firewall and Windows based slave publicly available.
The question is how to leverage that slave when it couldn't access master?

I followed [this guide](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines) but it assumes that slave could access master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slave talks to master for connection initialization.
Master send commands to slave for job execution.
Slave sends back to master the status of jobs.

You can't have that without a two-way communication between them.

Comment: I believe it is possible to accomplish this task in one-way manner. As designed :/